# how to sumproduct between many colums in R

Tags: r

could someone help me to calculate sumproduct in a data.table where I want to sumproduct the first columns and the rest? I mean if I have 10 columns I would like to sumproduct the first one with the second one, etc until I would sumproduct the first one and the last one).
The catch is that each time I might get different number of columns and columns but the principle is every time the same. I have tried this code:

```
sumproduct <- numeric(length(data) - 1)

for (i in 2:length(data)) {

  sumproduct[i-1] <- sum(data$x1 * data[, i])

}
```

and it works for some generic data.table of few columns, but not for hundreds of columns. Can somebody please help?

If i try the above code it works just for small data.table. For bigger id does not

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The natural data structure in R to do something like this is a matrix, not a data.frame.

```r
df <- data.frame(matrix(1:1000, ncol = 10))
M <- as.matrix(df)

crossprod(M[, 1], M[, 2:ncol(M)])

#         X2      X3      X4      X5      X6      X7      X8      X9     X10
# [1,] 843350 1348350 1853350 2358350 2863350 3368350 3873350 4378350 4883350
```